# PHP and SQL - Consult and WHERE clause with variable

Tags: php, sql, variables, where-clause, fetch

I'm actually coding the schedule of some conferences and I'm a little bit derping with the php code.

The code is the following:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
mysql_select_db("pbeusr3");

$sql="SELECT id_s, sessionname FROM sessions";


$result=mysql_query($sql);
$i=0;
if($result!=NULL)
{
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
           //here you can work with the results...
             echo "Session ".$row['id_s'].":" .$row['sessionname'];
             echo "<br>";
             $a = $row['id_s'];

             $sql2="SELECT id_p FROM presentations WHERE id_s='$a'";
             $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
             $sql3="SELECT title, author1 FROM papers WHERE id_p='$result2'";
             $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);

             while($row2=  mysql_fetch_array($result3))
             {
                 echo "Title ".$row2['title']. " Author: " .$row2['author1'];
                 echo "<br>";
             }

         }
    }
    else
    {
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

The output of this code is intended to be something like Session: Name of the session. Title of the paper and author of that session.

Instead I only see the Session and Name of the session (first fetch) but then I can't see the paper part (second fetch).

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: Look at where $result2 comes from, and where you're using it - it won't be the right type of data to substitute straight into the next query like that.

Comment: Also, have you looked into moving to MySQLi or PDO yet? The old mysql functions you're using here are no longer maintained, and will be removed in a future release of PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bit:

```
     $sql2="SELECT id_p FROM presentations WHERE id_s='$a'";
     $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
     $sql3="SELECT title, author1 FROM papers WHERE id_p='$result2'"; #<-- here
```

Is incorrect, you are trying to use the result set directly into the query. Instead, you need to retrieve that row and use that in your query like:

```
     $sql2="SELECT id_p FROM presentations WHERE id_s='$a'";
     $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
     //fetch the row from the result set
     $row_id_p = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
     $sql3="SELECT title, author1 FROM papers WHERE id_p='".$row_id_p['id_p']."'";
```

#### Note:

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$sql="SELECT id_s, sessionname FROM sessions";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$i=0;

    if(!empty($result))
    {
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
           //here you can work with the results...
             echo "Session ".$row['id_s'].":" .$row['sessionname'];
             echo "<br>";
             $a = $row['id_s'];

             $sql2="SELECT id_p FROM presentations WHERE id_s='$a'";
             $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
             if(!empty($result2))
             { 
                 $rowselect=  mysql_fetch_array($result2)
                 $b = $rowselect['id_p']; 
             }else $b='';
             $sql3="SELECT title, author1 FROM papers WHERE id_p='$b' ";
             $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);

             if(!empty($result3))
             {
                 while($row2=  mysql_fetch_array($result3))
                 {
                     echo "Title ".$row2['title']. " Author: " .$row2['author1'];
                     echo "<br>";
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                  //else statement if needed
             } 
             echo "<br>";

         }
    }
    else
    {
         //else statement
    }
  mysql_free_result($result);


mysql_close();
?>
```